# Android Master detail template - how to transfer variable from master list item to detail fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using master detail flow template to display three tables from SAP via SAP Mobile Platform. From the first activity which is only a list of Headers of Work order I choose one Header (Work order) and display list of items in Master activity (ItemListActivity). That I can do, but now when I click on item I have to forward one Long variable (surrogateKey) so that I can load details of that item as well as two more lists on detail activity. I made layout but when I run it throws nullPointerException error in onCreateView of ItemDetailFragment. 
This is from ItemListFragment :

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    Item item = items.get(position);
    long surrogateKey = item.getSurrogateKey();

    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(surrogateKey);

}
```

This is from ItemListActivity :

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(Long surrogateKey) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
        // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
        // fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putLong(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, surrogateKey);
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();

    } else {
        // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
        // for the selected item ID.
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(ItemListActivity.this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra("surrogateKey", surrogateKey);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

This is from ItemDetailActivity :

```
        // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
        // using a fragment transaction.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.getLong(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, 0);
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
```

And in onCreate of ItemDetailFragment:

```
    surrogateKeyItem = getArguments().getLong(ARG_ITEM_ID);
```

which have the right value (from debugging), but here in onCreateView it breaks on setText:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail,
            container, false);

    Item item = Item.find(surrogateKeyItem);

    final EditText psmc = (EditText)this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editPsmc);
    psmc.setText(item.getPOCETNOSMC().toString());
```

What I'm doing wrong?

This is from LogCat:

02-03 23:33:41.889: D/AndroidRuntime(22361): Shutting down VM 02-03 23:33:41.889: W/dalvikvm(22361): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415622a0) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): java.lang.NullPointerException 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at andrzg.zaga.app.md.ItemDetailFragment.onCreateView(ItemDetailFragment.java:97) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761) 02-03 23:33:41.944: E/AndroidRuntime(22361): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Just curious - have you checked the SurrogateKey != null before putting it in the bundle?

Comment: No because if item is displayed than it have surrogateKey. That is how SAP Mobile Server maintain relationships between Mobile Business Objects. And that I checked in debugger.

Comment: Post full stack trace please.

Comment: Also - I'm not familiar with your library, but you're using a static Item.find() call to locate the item associated with your surrogate key.  My guess is that this item is then causing the null at psmc.setText()?

Comment: Yes I just debug on tablet and it load Item object just before setting those EditTexts but value for this fields is 0 because they need to be  entered in application and then updated to SAP. This works fine on just Activity but here on Mater detail with fragments it throws nullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your editPsmc EditText inside the fragment_item_detail layout file?

If it is you should grab the EditText like this:

```
final EditText psmc = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editPsmc);
```

I think your null pointer is because the EditText psmc is null and you can't call setText() on a null object.

**EDIT:**

Inside your Activity you want to retrieve the key this way:

```
long key = getIntent().getLongExtra("surrogateKey", 0);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Just one more question. Now it works on tablet but not on phone. You can see that in onItemSelected for twoPane makes Bundle (arguments) and for single pane makes detailIntent. Do I must use same logic when loading surrogateKey in detail fragment or what?

Comment: Ok I did like this and it works :)    if (rootView.findViewById(R.id.item_detail_container) != null) {
   mTwoPane = true; }
  if (mTwoPane) {
  surrogateKeyItem = getArguments().getLong(ARG_ITEM_ID);
  } else {
   surrogateKeyItem = this.getActivity().getIntent().getLongExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, 0);
  }
  Item item = Item.find(surrogateKeyItem);